# LED Multiplexing - Large Matrices - Efficient Selection of Scanline Groups

Tags: multiplexer, led-driver, thermal, scanning

I have a `4 x 8` matrix of RGB 8-segment displays, (short for a 7-segment 'digit' plus a dot pixel, for which each segment (as well as dot) contains: 1x red LED, 1x green LED, and 1x blue LED).

To drive them, I will be using the [`TLC6983`](https://www.ti.com/product/TLC6983) [`[DataSheet]`](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tlc6983). This driver multiplexes the LEDs using 16 scanlines, however, I need to determine the scanline groupings.

### Question

What are the tradeoffs between scanline configurations when dividing the matrix into differently shaped subsets? Does simultaneously enabling LEDs localized in a compact area (and then not at all for an increased duration) improve or worsen characteristics such as:

- Thermals
- EMI
- Anything else

### Example scanline configurations

| qty | spatial relation | shape | @ | segments / digit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | adjacent | rows | @ | 1 |
| 4 | adjacent | columns | @ | 1 |
| 2 | adjacent | digits | @ | 8 |
| 4 | distributed | rows | @ | 1 |
| 4 | distributed | columns | @ | 1 |
| 2 | distributed | digits | @ | 8 |
| 16 | distributed | digits | @ | 1 |

I assume that scanning on distributed shapes (example: rows 1,3 then 2,4) is thermally better than adjacent shapes (example: rows 1,2 then 3,4), but maybe if everything is cycling at such a high rate, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Could you clarify 4 x 8 x rgb 7seg+dot ... do you mean you have 32 digits each of 8 LED triples?  Ie 256 red + 256 green + 256 blue LEDs, a total of 768?

Comment: @jonathanjo : Totes that exactly : j

Comment: @jonathanjo : Edited for added clarity.

Comment: Usually you'd organise it for best PCB layout, which keeps your lines short and organised, with the fewest vias.  The other consideration is organising the scan rate to be as fast as possible to reduce flicker -- some people notice much faster flicker rates than others.  Thermal makes no difference because persistance of vision is much faster than the thermal conduction.

Comment: Oh yeah, flicker is assumed to be ≥ 2 [kHz] and layout will be optimized — the IC will be dead center in the LED matrix and there will be a fair number of layers. That leaves the remaining question : Does simultaneously enabling LEDs closer together or farther apart have any effect?

Comment: What power of LEDs do you have?

Comment: Electrical or luminous? V.f.blueGreen ≤ 3.5 [V], V.f.red ≤ 3.0 [V]. I.f.nom = 20 [mA]. I_v.nom < 100 [mcd] after PWM.

Comment: I struggle to think of anything (other than might be seen with photography) that would be different solely changing the multiplexing pattern.